# How to get Exposure Compensation Index in Auto Exposure?

Tags: android, camera

I am developing a custom camera,

I need to know exact Exposure Compensation Index when in Auto Exposure mode.

So I set AutoExposureLock to false and start reading the Exposure Compensation:

int currentExpIndex = params.getExposureCompensation();

As I point the camera to dark and bright areas, the camera adjusts the exposure, making it brighter or darker.

But currentExpIndex is always 0.

Can you help me - why is it?

Comment: I've got exactly the same behaviour with the front camera on my Sony Xperia M. None of the exposure methods seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: After reading a lot of article on this subject, the verdict is like this: as a rule, camera lives its own life, and Android has very little impact on it, at least in terms of exposure. You can lock/unlock it, but adjusting / reading exact exposure is generally impossible.